# Why is my sqlalchemy model not callable?

Tags: python

I'm following the [official sqlalchemy tutorial](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html) on getting started, yet when I try to instantiate the User class below, I'm told by the interpreter that it's not callable. I have no idea why. Anyone have any idea?

**__init__.py**

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()
```

**user.py**

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String

from __init__ import Base


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    fullname = Column(String)
    password = Column(String)
```

**user_api.py**

```
from flask import request
from flask.views import MethodView

from src.main.model.user import User


class UserAPI(MethodView):
    def post(self):
        usr = User(**request.form)
        return usr
```

**__main__.py**

```
import flask
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

from src.main.endpoints.user_api import UserAPI
from src.main.model import Base

def database_stuff():
    engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=True)
    Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    database_stuff()
    app = flask.Flask(__name__)
    user_view = UserAPI.as_view("users")
    app.add_url_rule("/users/", defaults={"user_id": None}, view_func=user_view, methods=["GET"])
    app.add_url_rule("/users/", view_func=user_view, methods=["POST"])
    app.add_url_rule("/users/<int:user_id>", view_func=user_view, methods=["GET"])
    app.run()
```

When attempting to do a post request to the Flask server, this is what I'm getting in the logs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Documents\python\flaskplay\flaskplay\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "D:\Documents\python\flaskplay\flaskplay\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1615, in full_dispatch_request
    return self.finalize_request(rv)
  File "D:\Documents\python\flaskplay\flaskplay\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1630, in finalize_request
    response = self.make_response(rv)
  File "D:\Documents\python\flaskplay\flaskplay\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1740, in make_response
    rv = self.response_class.force_type(rv, request.environ)
  File "D:\Documents\python\flaskplay\flaskplay\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\wrappers.py", line 885, in force_type
    response = BaseResponse(*_run_wsgi_app(response, environ))
  File "D:\Documents\python\flaskplay\flaskplay\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\wrappers.py", line 57, in _run_wsgi_app
    return _run_wsgi_app(*args)
  File "D:\Documents\python\flaskplay\flaskplay\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\test.py", line 884, in run_wsgi_app
    app_rv = app(environ, start_response)
TypeError: 'User' object is not callable
127.0.0.1 - - [05/Jun/2017 20:44:32] "POST /users/ HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

Comment: Include the definition of `__init__.py::Base`

Comment: @wim Included, cheers.

Comment: Could you include the full exception?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Included, cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It actually has nothing to do with sqlalchemy. The object is indeed callable and instantiable. The error actually comes with attempting to return the object as a response. You can't just return any old object from a Flask endpoint. If I convert the object dict to json, then the error is no longer applicable.